# Flutter: push multiple pages on stack

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I am using `Getx` for route management.

When coming from deepLink and the app is terminated, I want the app to launch (with splashscreen) and then go to a specific `/match/:match_id` route (I have the id in the deepLink).

This works well. The problem is that I want to push below this match page, the `home` page so that when the user goes back he can go there.

Within the `initState` of the `LaunchScreen` widget I am doing

```
Get.offNamed("/home");                     // remove `LaunchScreen` and push `Home`
Get.offNamed("/match/:" + match_id);       // push `Match`
```

This works. However there is some inconsistency with animations. I see for few seconds the `Home` page and then immediately the `Match`

I would like to jump directly to `Match` and the user not even seeing the `Home` one